# Load Spring Boot component before Lombok instantation in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4, lombok

I developed a kind of *wrapper* to make it work as a custom logger. I'm instantiating this class using `@CustomLog` Lombok annotation just to make it easier and cleaner. The tricky thing comes next: the idea behind this wrapper is to use a common logger (as `org.slf4j.Logger`) along with a custom monitor class that each time I call `log.error()`, the proper message gets logged in the terminal and the event is sent to my monitoring tool (Prometheus in this case).

To achieve this I did the following classes:

1. `CustomLoggerFactory` the factory called by Lombok to instantiate my custom logger.

```java
public final class CustomLoggerFactory {

     public static CustomLogger getLogger(String className) {

        return new CustomLogger(className);
     }
}
```

2. `CustomLogger` will receive the class name just to then call `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

```java
public class CustomLogger {

    private org.slf4j.Logger logger;
    private PrometheusMonitor prometheusMonitor;
    private String className;

    public CustomLogger(String className) {

        this.logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(className);
        this.className = className;
        this.monitor = SpringContext.getBean(PrometheusMonitor.class);
    }
}
```

3. `PrometheusMonitor` class is the one in charge of creating the metrics and that kind of things. The most important thing here is that **it's being managed by Spring Boot**.

```java
@Component
public class PrometheusMonitor {

    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public PrometheusMonitor(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }
}
```

4. As you may noticed, to access `PrometheusMonitor` from `CustomLogger` I need an additional class in order to get the Bean / access the context from a non Spring managed class. This is the `SpringContext` class which has an `static` method to get the bean by the class supplied.

```java
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

So all this works just fine when running the application. I ensure to load `SpringContext` class before anything else, so once each `CustomLogger` gets instantiated it just works.

But the **BIG** issue comes here: this is not working while unit testing my app. I tried many things and I saw some solutions that may help me but that I'm trying to avoid (e.g. using PowerMockito). Lombok is processing `@CustomLog` annotation before any `@Before` method I add to my test class. Once `getBean()` method is called I get an exception cause `context` is `null`.

My guesses are that I could solve it if I can *force* the `SpringContext` to be loaded before Lombok does its magic, but I'm not sure that's even possible. Many thanks for taking your time to read this. Any more info I can provide just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve this issue changing a little how the `CustomLogger` works. Meaning that instead of instantiating `monitor` field along with the logger, you can do it the first time you'll use it. E.g.:

```java
public class CustomLogger {

    private org.slf4j.Logger logger;
    private Monitor monitor;

    public CustomLogger(String className) {
        this.logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(className);
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        this.logger.info(message);
    }

    public void error(String message) {
        this.logger.error(message);
        if (this.monitor == null) {
            this.monitor = SpringContext.getBean(PrometheusMonitor.class);
        }
        this.monitor.send(message);
    }
}
```

But after all I decided to not follow this approach because I don't think it's the best one possible and worth it.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: It sounds like your custom logging needs are better served by logging to slf4j as normal, and registering an additional handler with the slf4j framework so that slf4j will forward any logs to you (in addition to the other handlers, such as the one making the log files).

> Lombok is processing @CustomLog

The generated log field is  static. If an annotation is going to help at all, you'd need `@BeforeClass`, but that probably also isn't in time. Lombok's magic doesn't seem relevant here. Check out what delombok tells you lombok is doing: It's just.. a static field, being initialized on declaration.

Comment: At first I thought in something like that (handling logs events sent by other framework) but for the logs I have right now I'm using some custom parameters as `enum`s that can't be sent along with Slf4j log invocations. So I can't see a way handling could properly meet my needs.